# Rails add one to increment SQL value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to add one to the already incremented field in the DB, but I am getting the following error: `NoMethodError (undefined method`+' for false:FalseClass):`

Code:

```
med = Media.find(params[:media_id])
med.update_attributes({:screener_viewed => med.screener_viewed + 1})
```

I am just wanting to add `1` to the current value of screener_viewed, but can't get it to work.

Working Code:

```
Media.increment_counter(:screener_viewed, params[:media_id])
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `increment!`:

```
med.increment!(:screener_viewed)
```

Make sure that `screener_viewed` is of type integer in your db.

Comment: I actually just found this after refining my Google search! I am still new to Rails and I have no idea where it has been ALL my life, but I am definitely loving every minute of it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad this helped. Rails is definitely an eye-opener. I would advise you to also learn more about ruby itself. The awesomeness of Rails is in large part due to the "ruby way".

Answer (score 0):

Examine the error message carefully. It says there is no addition method defined for the FalseClass, which means that screener_viewed contains a boolean value of false. Did you expect it to contain an integer, or are you trying to flip the value to true?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the migration definition for the Media model? It looks like you've defined it as a Boolean, which does not support the + operator:

```
irb(main):002:0> false + 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for false:FalseClass
        from (irb):2
```

Answer (score 0):

Careful about using increment! I does not support concurrent request.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!